# Windows command line tool to process text into fixed width paragraphs

Tags: command-line

I'm looking for a Windows command line tool to process text into fixed width paragraphs.

The source text file will just be a few pages of text in paragraphs.

I want to convert it to fixed width paragraphs, so that it still reads OK when the user opens it in Notepad without word wrap.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the *nix tool `fold`. It's availible in Cygwin, if you already have it, or [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/), and probably some other ports I'm unaware of.

Usage like:

```
fold -4 file.txt
```

to fold into 4-character lines. (Outputs to Standard Output, so don't forget to redirect to another file :))